# $q defer in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q, angular-promise

I simplified the code to solve a specific problem.

I have 2 functions at $scope: *singleRequest()* and *multiReqest()*.
*multiReqest()* must call *testServer()* several time and then call *singleRequest()*.

Problem in this example: *singleRequest()* called before *multiReqest()* started, but at the same time *console.log('All requests from multiRequest loaded')* called in turn.
Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $q, $http) {

//variables declaration etc

var testServer = function (_pos) {
    console.log('testServer:', _pos)
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(service.first, parameters).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(_pos, 'request from multiRequest loaded');
        //do smth with data
        deferred.resolve();
    }).error(function (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
//
//
$scope.singleRequest = function () {
    console.log('Start singleRequest function');
    $http.get(service.second).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('Single request loaded');
        //do smth with data
    });
};
//
//
$scope.multiRequest = function (_callback) {
    console.log('Start multiRequest function');
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        promises.push(testServer(i));
    }
    $q.all(promises).then(function () {
        console.log('All requests from multiRequest loaded');
        _callback;
    });
};
//
$scope.multiRequest($scope.singleRequest());
}
```

**console log:**

- Start singleRequest function
- Start multiRequest function
- testServer:  1
- testServer:  2
- testServer:  3
- Single request loaded. XHR finished loading: GET "http://...
- 1 "request from multiRequest loaded". XHR finished loading: GET "http://...
- 2 "request from multiRequest loaded". XHR finished loading: GET "http://...
- 3 "request from multiRequest loaded". XHR finished loading: GET "http://...
- All requests from multiRequest loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing a callback, but actually calling the function here:

```
$scope.multiRequest($scope.singleRequest()); // Passing return value
```

So you should change that to:

```
$scope.multiRequest($scope.singleRequest); // Passing function
```

Then change `_callback;` to `_callback();`, to call the function.

Comment: It works! Thank you ! Not accustomed after C-language transfer the variable names as a pointer to a function .
But if I need to be passed callback function with parameters, eg $scope.multiRequest (foo (bar));  ?

Comment: Then you can wrap it in another function if the parameters are not known where the callback is called. E.g. `$scope.multiRequest(function () { foo(bar, widget); });`.